# How is yc (complimentary function) a solution for a non homogeneous linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's intuitive to see that particular solution of a linear differential equation is its solution but how is complimentary solution its solution? When you put it back into the equation you always end up with 0=r(x).

Answer (score 1):

The complementary solution is not a solution to the non-homogeneous equation.  It is a solution to the homogeneous one.  Once you have $y_c$, the solutions to the non-homogeneous equation is the sum of a particular solution with $y_c$.

Comment: So why do we need to include it in the solution in the first place? It just sits there always turning into zero.

Comment: @AdityaKumarGupta It's a bit like calculus.  If you want to solve $f'(x)=g(x)$, your solutions are a particular antiderivative of $g(x)$ plus some constant $C$.  So, the $C$ is your solution to the homogeneous equation $f'(x)=0$.  Adding in the homogeneous party makes sure that you get all of your solutions.